# get a column showing the index of the operation for every distinct day

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that stores operations on different days. Is it possible to get a column showing the index of the operation for every distinct day?

this is my table:

```
id    date          sum
 1    2014-01-03    -31.00
 2    2014-01-03    +21.21
 4    2014-01-03    - 2.90
 5    2014-01-12    +10.00
 6    2014-01-18    -18.93
 8    2014-01-24    - 4.38
11    2014-01-24    - 6.00
```

this is what my query should show:

```
id    date          sum       index
 1    2014-01-03    -31.00        1  -- first operation on the 2014-01-03
 2    2014-01-03    +21.21        2  -- second operation on the 2014-01-03
 4    2014-01-03    - 2.90        3  -- etc...
 5    2014-01-12    +10.00        1
 6    2014-01-18    -18.93        1
 8    2014-01-24    - 4.38        1
11    2014-01-24    - 6.00        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With other DBMS this would be very easy using window functions. But SQLite doesn't support them, so you need to use a co-related sub-query which makes this quite slow:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.date, 
       t1.sum, 
       (select count(*) from the_table t2 where t2.date = t1.date and t2.id <= t1.id) as idx
from the_table t1
order by date, id;
```

But as I said: this **is** going to be slow!

---

<sup>Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a reserved word, but more importantly because it doesn't document what the column stores. An order date? An expiration date? A due date? ...</sup>